# Bind client name to priority

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Simple CRUD app, client list view and detail view. I'd like the list view to sort on the server, so I should set priority on the client FireBase references.

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller 'ClientsDetailCtrl', ($scope, $routeParams, angularFire) ->
    fb = new Firebase('https://myurl.firebaseio.com/clients/' + $routeParams.id)

    angularFire(fb, $scope, 'client')

    $scope.$watch('client.name', (newValue) -> 
        fb.setPriority(newValue) if newValue != undefined)
```

Every time the client.name changes, I set the priority on the FireBase ref. However, the priority is null when I get back to the list page. I think this happens because changing the name calls set() on the reference, which clears the priority.

What's the easiest way to accomplish setting the priority to the client.name? I could try using $timeout, but that would get overwritten when a value besides the client.name is modified.

Comment: This is a known bug in AngularFire: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/116 - stay tuned for a fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is fixed now in AngularFire.